# input the date but the date value is not found

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tuRN.png)

A message box will pop up for user to input the date and copy and paste the Money value to a new cell. Whenever i input the date. the value is always not found.
Below is the code:

```
`your text`Macro10 Macro
'
Sub get_money()
    a_col_last_row = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    d_col_last_row = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    data_a = InputBox("Enter 1st date")
    data_d = InputBox("Enter 2st date")
    lookup_val_a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 8)
    Dim refRng_a As Range
    Dim refRng_d As Range
    Set refRng_a = Range("A2:B" & a_col_last_row)
    'data_a = Cells(3, 8).Value
    Set refRng_d = Range("D2:E" & d_col_last_row)
    'data_d = Cells(3, 9).Value
    On Error GoTo errhandler1:
    Cells(3, 8) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(data_a, refRng_a, 2, 0)
controlback:
    On Error GoTo errhandler2:
    Cells(3, 9) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(data_d, refRng_d, 2, 0)
    
    End
errhandler1:
    MsgBox "1st Value not found"
    Err.Number = 0
    Resume controlback
    
errhandler2:
    MsgBox " 2nd Value not found"
    Err.Number = 0
End Sub
```

The user need to input the date and the value besides the date will copy and paste to the new cell.

Comment: Set a `Break Point`at the first line of code after the `Sub` statement, then run your code and step through each line with `F8`. Hover over your variables at each line to make sure they're what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that InputBox returns String data type. You need
a) declare date variables as Date
for example,

```
Dim data_a as Date
```

b) convert data to Date
for example, `data_a = CDate(InputBox("Enter 1st date"))`